# Restrict authorization or reduce result in case specific parameter arent satisfy requirements

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Describing University via software I faced an auth issue.

Previously I had only a `Headmaster` role, which can do and access anything.
But as for now, I need to integrate a `Teacher` role.

The `Teacher` role should have an option to access certain features, which could be easily restricted by `Authorize` attribute. But in some cases, I want to reduce the number of data allowed to access for this role, e.g. not all students of the universe, but the ones who study `Teacher's` `Subject`.

All of this is already described in EF, (e.g. teacher-subject, subject-students relationships). But now I struggle to refuse (return 403) request for subject or students which are not allowed to access by `Teacher`.

I thought about a Specification pattern usage for my Services, so the resulting data will be reduced with a Specification's filter, as it helps reduce the data amount, sometimes to no-data, but didn't help to fully refuse a request.

Could you kindly provide me a link or an architectural idea to satisfy expectations for both use-cases specified above?

```
// entity models
class Subject {
    ...
    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
    public List<Students> { get; set; }
    ...
}

class Teacher {
    ...
    public List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
    ...
}
class Student {
    ...
    public List<Subject> StudiedSubjects {get; set; }
    ...
}

// first use-case I want to solve
public ActionResult<List<Student>> GetStudent()
{
    // previously I just did
    return Ok(_studentsService.GetStudents());

    // but as for now in case of Teacher role accessed the method I want to
    // reduce the number of returned students
}

// second use-case I want to solve
public ActionResult<Subject> GetSubjectDetails(int subjectId)
{
    // previously I just did
    return Ok(_subjectService.GetSubject(subjectId);

    // but as for now in case of Teacher role I need to check whether its
    // allowed to get the subject and return Access denied in case its not
}
```

Comment: Sequrity in DDD article might be really useful https://www.utwente.nl/en/eemcs/trese/graduation_projects/2008/Uithol.pdf

Comment: Perfect Question. This will make people understand the real use cases for Roles and Claims

Comment: Because of the amount of ways to solve this problem, I believe this is a primarily opinion based question. I did write an answer which I removed, but personally I wouldn't handle this through user roles. have a table of class Ids and teacher Ids, if the classID maps to the teacher ID return student that have that classID else return 403

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your first case, because the Action have no parameters at all, it'll make more sense to return Students that are accessible for a Teacher, or no Students at all if no one take all the subjects of certain Teacher, so 403 are not needed in this case. You could pass the `User` from controller or [inject HttpContextAssessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.2#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components) to StudentService and use it for filtering.

as for your second case, its a perfect situation to return 403 if the `SubjectId` is not related to the `Teacher` in context. If you dont mind getting data from database for each request, you can use [Requirement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2#requirements) combined [AuthorizationHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2#authorization-handlers) in a Policy-Based Authorization by retrieving any data you need for authorization from database thus determine if the teacher has access to certain Subject(s). Steps to achieve it:

First setup the policy for the Teachers-Subjects relation and the handlers in `Startup.ConfigureServices` :

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("TeacherSubject", policy => policy.Requirements.Add( new TeacherSubjectRequirement() ));
});
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, TeacherSubjectHandler>();
```

next create the AuthorizationHandler for that policy:

```
public class TeacherSubjectHandler : AuthorizationHandler<TeacherSubjectRequirement>
{
    readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
    readonly UserManager<AppUser> _usermanager;
    readonly UserToTeacherService _userToTeacherService;

    public ThePolicyAuthorizationHandler(IHttpContextAccessor c, UserManager<AppUser> u, _userToTeacherService s)
    {
        _contextAccessor = c;
        _userManager = u;
        _userToTeacherService = s;
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext authHandlerContext, TeacherSubjectRequirement requirement)
    {
        var user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(_contextAccessor.HttpContext.User);
        var teacher = _userToTeacherService(user); //I assume this service will also retrieve teacher's subjects
        var subjectIds = teacher.Subjects.Select(s => s.SubjectId).ToList();

        if (context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
        {
            var subjectIdStr = filterContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();
            if ( int.TryParse(subjectIdStr, out var subjectId) && subjectIds.Contains(subjectId) )
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }

        } 

    }
}
```

as for the Requirement class, its just an empty class:

```
public class TeacherSubjectRequirement: IAuthorizationRequirement
{

}
```

Since we're doing the authorization mechanism in AuthorizationHandler, we can leave this class empty. But it will still needed for the policy-based authorization to works.

And then for the policy to take effect, add attribute to the controller

```
[Authorize(Policy = "TeacherSubject")]
public ActionResult<Subject> GetSubjectDetails(int subjectId)
{
    //existing code
}
```

But to be honest, I haven't tried putting policy-based attribute in an Action. If this doesn't work, putting the attribute in controller will surely works.

Hope this helps.

Comment: JFYI I've successfully implemented a provided solution in the project and it works as expected.

Comment: @JohnDoe do you put the attribute in the action or in controller?

Comment: It works for action only as well, but I use it with a controller.

Comment: Good answer there. Just an addition, calling `context.Fail()` is not recommend. The idea is that you can have multiple handlers against a single requirement, which may use different criteria to check if the requirement 'passes'. In the example, you can have another handler that checks if the teacher is holding a gun. Now, if you call `context.Fail()` you are essentially saying that requirement has failed completely, no other handler can deem it passed under any other criteria. Just leave it open and when no handler calls `context.Succeed(...)` the framework will then consider it as failed.

Comment: @gerryc.inc thanks for the comment, I agree its better without calling context.Fail(). answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario is very practical which makes the question very interesting. But It would be nice for you to look at this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio).

Use claims to give the teach access to the information they must be able to access. You can save a claim as .i.e. "TeacherName-TargetInforNameTheyCanAccess"; you can have as many claims as possible depending on how much information should be accessible by the teacher.

This goes the same for Students as well. You can create claims for Students that are under that Lecturers Class. Like say: "StudentName-LectureName" an you can then base your authentication by checking if the student is claimed to be under a specific lecturers class.