# How to use ASP.NET Core resource-based authorization without duplicating if/else code everywhere

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-identity

I have a dotnet core 2.2 api with some controllers and action methods that needs to be authorized based on a user claim and the resource being accessed. Basically, each user can have 0 or many "roles" for each resource. This is all done using ASP.NET Identity Claims.

So, my understanding is that I need to make use of [Resource-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.2). But both examples there are mostly identical and require the explicit imperative if/else logic on each action method, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

I want to be able to do something like

```
[Authorize("Admin")] // or something similar
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSomething(int resourceId)
{
   var resource = await SomeRepository.Get(resourceId);

   return Json(resource);
}
```

And somewhere else define the authorization logic as a policy/filter/requirement/whatever and have access to both the current user claims and the `resourceId` parameter received by the endpoint. So there I can see if the user has a claim that denotes that he has the "Admin" role for that specific `resourceId`.

Comment: can you please take a look at my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56324892/restrict-authorization-or-reduce-result-in-case-specific-parameter-arent-satisfy ?
can it solve your problem?

Comment: You can try Casbin.NET: https://github.com/casbin/Casbin.NET  It supports resource-based RBAC.

Comment: I wrote a post on this, https://undocumented.dev/declarative-resource-based-authorisation-with-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 7):

**Edit: Based on feedback to make it dynamic**

The key thing with RBAC and claims in .NET, is to create your ClaimsIdentity and then let the framework do it's job.  Below is an example middleware that will look at the query parameter "user" and then generate the ClaimsPrincipal based on a dictionary.

To avoid the need to actually wire up to an identity provider, I created a Middleware that sets up the ClaimsPrincipal:

```
// **THIS CLASS IS ONLY TO DEMONSTRATE HOW THE ROLES NEED TO BE SETUP **
public class CreateFakeIdentityMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CreateFakeIdentityMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    private readonly Dictionary<string, string[]> _tenantRoles = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
    {
        ["tenant1"] = new string[] { "Admin", "Reader" },
        ["tenant2"] = new string[] { "Reader" },
    };

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Assume this is the roles
        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "John"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "john@someemail.com")
        };

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string[]> tenantRole in _tenantRoles)
        {
            claims.AddRange(tenantRole.Value.Select(x => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, $"{tenantRole.Key}:{x}".ToLower())));
        }
        
        // Note: You need these for the AuthorizeAttribute.Roles    
        claims.AddRange(_tenantRoles.SelectMany(x => x.Value)
            .Select(x => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, x.ToLower())));

        context.User = new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims,
            "Bearer"));

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

To wire this up, just use the [UseMiddleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.usemiddlewareextensions.usemiddleware?view=aspnetcore-2.2) extension method for [IApplicationBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.iapplicationbuilder?view=aspnetcore-2.2) in your startup class.

```
app.UseMiddleware<RBACExampleMiddleware>();
```

I create an AuthorizationHandler which will look for the query parameter "tenant" and either succeed or fail based on the roles.

```
public class SetTenantIdentityHandler : AuthorizationHandler<TenantRoleRequirement>
{
    public const string TENANT_KEY_QUERY_NAME = "tenant";

    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string[]> _methodRoles = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string[]>();

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, TenantRoleRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (HasRoleInTenant(context))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private bool HasRoleInTenant(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        if (context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext authorizationFilterContext)
        {
            if (authorizationFilterContext.HttpContext
                .Request
                .Query
                .TryGetValue(TENANT_KEY_QUERY_NAME, out StringValues tenant)
                && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tenant))
            {
                if (TryGetRoles(authorizationFilterContext, tenant.ToString().ToLower(), out string[] roles))
                {
                    if (context.User.HasClaim(x => roles.Any(r => x.Value == r)))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private bool TryGetRoles(AuthorizationFilterContext authorizationFilterContext,
        string tenantId,
        out string[] roles)
    {
        string actionId = authorizationFilterContext.ActionDescriptor.Id;
        roles = null;

        if (!_methodRoles.TryGetValue(actionId, out roles))
        {
            roles = authorizationFilterContext.Filters
                .Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(AuthorizeFilter))
                .Select(x => x as AuthorizeFilter)
                .Where(x => x != null)
                .Select(x => x.Policy)
                .SelectMany(x => x.Requirements)
                .Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(RolesAuthorizationRequirement))
                .Select(x => x as RolesAuthorizationRequirement)
                .SelectMany(x => x.AllowedRoles)
                .ToArray();

            _methodRoles.TryAdd(actionId, roles);
        }

        roles = roles?.Select(x => $"{tenantId}:{x}".ToLower())
            .ToArray();

        return roles != null;
    }
}
```

The TenantRoleRequirement is a very simple class:

```
public class TenantRoleRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement { }
```

Then you wire everything up in the startup.cs file like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, SetTenantIdentityHandler>();

// Although this isn't used to generate the identity, it is needed
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Audience = "https://localhost:5000/";
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5000/identity/";
});

services.AddAuthorization(authConfig =>
{
    authConfig.AddPolicy(Policies.HasRoleInTenant, policyBuilder => {
        policyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policyBuilder.AddRequirements(new TenantRoleRequirement());
    });
});
```

The method looks like this:

```
// TOOD: Move roles to a constants/globals
[Authorize(Policy = Policies.HasRoleInTenant, Roles = "admin")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

Below are the test scenarios:

1. Positive: https://localhost:44337/api/values?tenant=tenant1
2. Negative: https://localhost:44337/api/values?tenant=tenant2
3. Negative: https://localhost:44337/api/values

The key thing with this approach is that I never actually return a 403.  The code setups the identity and then lets the framework handle the result.  This ensures authentication is separate from authorization.

Comment: Can you show how you call `RBACExampleMiddleware` and how that relates to the `Authorize` attribute. *You don't need any custom attributes, just use the built in ones to secure your methods.* - isn't very clear

Comment: So, let me get this straight. You suggest that I should create a Claim based on my custom authorization logic and then use the standard Authorize filter to let the framework do the actual authorization? I think I understand your point. But, why do you say creating your custom AuthorizationFilter is buggy?

Also, I need to access the Claims for the current user that are set by IdentityServer4 and sent along with the token.That's where the information about which permission does the current user has for a specific resource is. I guess I can access those inside the middleware, right?

Comment: @JeremyThompson I updated my answer to show how to wire up middleware in .NET Core.  I also added links to the classes for your reference.  Finally, this walks through how middleware works and how the order of execution happens: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @emzero The reason why I say creating a custom AuthorizationFilter  is buggy is because this requires you to understand protocols to ensure your response are accurate.  I would much rather use builtin framework or a NuGet package that handles generating the response.  Additionally, you will find yourself mixing the custom code with the builtin, and you may accidentally make something available.  Instead, I have found it is better to add the claims, and let .NET Core handle the rest.  Check out this link: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/8_aspnet_identity.html

Comment: @emzero if you have questions on how to get the claims, send me a message and I'll be happy to help out

Comment: @JeremyThompson please also note, the middleware was just for demonstration purposes to show how the AuthorizeAttribute works.  It's not intended to be part of the solution.

Comment: The thing is, when I say resource I don't mean a type of resource as in your example. Like, you have a controller for each resource type (BooksController, AuthorController, etc).
What I meant was a specific instance of a resource. In my case, the API is used for multiple tenant data on a multi-tenant application. So when a user requests data from an endpoint, we must first ensure that he has access to that particular tenant which is specified in the action parameters as `tenantId`. I can't just do `VALUES:Reader` as in your example. Continues on next comment.

Comment: Because my "VALUES" is actually a tenantId (received as a parameter in the query string). The RBAC data is already sent by IdentityServer in the token as a JSON shaped like `[{ "tenantId" = x, "role" = "roleName" }]`

Comment: @emzero if that is a collection, then just join the tenantId and role tenantId:role and add the role claim like that.  Then the resource is replaced with tenant.  Same pattern.  Make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196530/discussion-between-emzero-and-rogala).

Answer (score 3):

You could create your own attribute which will check the user's role. I have done this in one of my applications:

```
public sealed class RoleValidator : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<string> _roles;

    public RoleValidator(params string[] roles) => _roles = roles;

    public RoleValidator(string role) => _roles = new List<string> { role };

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Claims == null || filterContext.HttpContext.User.Claims?.Count() <= 0)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            return;
        }

        if (CheckUserRoles(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Claims))
            return;

        filterContext.Result = new ForbidResult();
    }

    private bool CheckUserRoles(IEnumerable<Claim> claims) =>
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RoleDto>>(claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals(ClaimType.Roles.ToString()))?.Value)
            .Any(x => _roles.Contains(x.Name));
}
```

It gets user role from claims and check is user have proper role to get this resouce. 
You can use it like this:

```
[RoleValidator("Admin")]
```

or better approach with enum:

```
[RoleValidator(RoleType.Admin)]
```

or you can pass a multiple roles:

```
[RoleValidator(RoleType.User, RoleType.Admin)]
```

With this solution you must also use the standard Authorize attribute.

Comment: You could use the `params` keyword to avoid passing an array : `public RoleValidator(params string[] roles) => _roles = roles;` and use it like this: `[RoleValidator("Admin", "User")]`

Comment: This is not taking in consideration the resource. I don't need to check if the user has a global "admin" role for example. I need to see if the user claims contains a role for the specific resourceId. The filter should make use of both the user claims and the resourceId received in the action method. So, how do I access the resourceId in the filter? Can I get it somehow from the filterContext?

Comment: While you could do this, I would avoid it.  Instead, I am a fan of using the built in security framework.

Comment: @Rogala Could you please expand on that? I don't think I can use the built-in security framework in my case because I need to do some custom authorization logic that depends on both the role name passed to the attribute and the resource trying to be accessed.

Comment: I would avoid this pattern, because the code sets the results.  If you are working with a specific protocol, then it may require a very specific response.  By doing this, you override the built-in handling of the response.  This is also not doing anything different that the [Authorize(Roles="User,Admin")]  Also, it's not recommended to do params as the constructor for attributes.  The best practice is to use comma delimited strings.

Answer (score 3):

**Edited based on comments**

According to my understanding, you want to access current user (all information related to it), the role(s) you want to specify for a controller (or action) and parameters received by endpoint. Haven't tried for web api, but for asp.net core MVC, You can achieve this by using `AuthorizationHandler` in a policy-based authorization and combine with an injected service specifically created to determine the Roles-Resources access.

To do it, first setup the policy in `Startup.ConfigureServices` :

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("UserResource", policy => policy.Requirements.Add( new UserResourceRequirement() ));
});
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, UserResourceHandler>();
services.AddScoped<IRoleResourceService, RoleResourceService>();
```

next create the `UserResourceHandler` :

```
public class UserResourceHandler : AuthorizationHandler<UserResourceRequirement>
{
    readonly IRoleResourceService _roleResourceService;

    public UserResourceHandler (IRoleResourceService r)
    {
        _roleResourceService = r;
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext authHandlerContext, UserResourceRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
        {
            var area = (filterContext.RouteData.Values["area"] as string)?.ToLower();
            var controller = (filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] as string)?.ToLower();
            var action = (filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"] as string)?.ToLower();
            var id = (filterContext.RouteData.Values["id"] as string)?.ToLower();
            if (_roleResourceService.IsAuthorize(area, controller, action, id))
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }               
        }            
    }
}
```

Accessing the parameters received by endpoint is achieved by casting `context.Resource` to `AuthorizationFilterContext`, so that we could access `RouteData` from it. As for `UserResourceRequirement`, we can leave it empty.

```
public class UserResourceRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement { }
```

As for the `IRoleResourceService`, it's a plain service class so that we can inject anything to it. This service is the substitute of pairing a Role to an action in code so that we don't need to specify it in action's attribute. That way, we can have a freedom to choose the implementation, ex: from database, from config file, or hard-coded.

Accessing user in `RoleResourceService` is achieved by injecting `IHttpContextAccessor`. Please note that to make `IHttpContextAccessor` injectable, add `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()` in `Startup.ConfigurationServices` method body.

Here's an example getting the info from config file:

```
public class RoleResourceService : IRoleResourceService
{
    readonly IConfiguration _config;
    readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
    readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;

    public class RoleResourceService(IConfiguration c, IHttpContextAccessor a, UserManager<AppUser> u) 
    {
        _config = c;
        _accessor = a;
        _userManager = u;
    }

    public bool IsAuthorize(string area, string controller, string action, string id)
    {
        var roleConfig = _config.GetValue<string>($"RoleSetting:{area}:{controller}:{action}"); //assuming we have the setting in appsettings.json
        var appUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(_accessor.HttpContext.User);
        var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(appUser);
        // all of needed data are available now, do the logic of authorization
        return result;
    } 
}
```

Get the setting from database surely is a bit more complex, but it can be done since we can inject `AppDbContext`. For the hardcoded approach, exist plenty ways to do it.

After all is done, use the policy on an action:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "UserResource")] //dont need Role name because of the RoleResourceService
public ActionResult<IActionResult> GetSomething(int resourceId)
{
    //existing code
}
```

In fact, we can use "UserResource" policy for any action that we want to apply.

Comment: Uhm, this seems a bit complex for what I need to do. Anyway, is there a way to pass an argument to the policy? Because I need 3 things: the resourceId (action method argument), the user claims and the policy/filter argument (the role in my example). So that I can use it as `[Authorize(Policy = "UserResource", RoleName = "Admin")]`. Is it possible?

Comment: Not that i know of. My solution seems a bit complex because it enables us to create just one policy for almost all possible scenarios. If you dont mind creating more than one policy, you can make one for each role, such as 'UserResourceAdmin', 'UserResourceStaff' and so on.

Comment: Edited the answer, the previous answers don't have a solution for RoleName in attribute. I still haven't got a solution for it, but propose an alternative that has an advantage.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to use the UserManager pattern.  Generally, web apps are token or cookie based.  This pattern does not separate the identity provider outside of the current application.  It also appears to be centralizing authentication with authorization which is not a good practice.  A better pattern is to go with a token based architecture

Comment: Its just to illustrate how to get roles from user, and user from ClaimsPrincipal. What I'm proposing is that we can specify what role can access an action in a plain service class. In my opinion, its more inline with the built-in policy and can have options in the implementation.

Comment: I originally liked the concept of using a configuration to manage the security, but then this would be prone to bugs.  If you rename do any renaming you have to do it in more than one place.  Additionally, configuration can be deployed without a rebuild, so you could accidentally release an open endpoint.  I would much rather my security code be explicit, and compiled.

Comment: You can hardcoded it if that's your preference, and use nameof(Action) as to avoid typo and let IDE do the renaming. I also agree its better this way, but sometimes clients insist on configurable and runtime-changable security setting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Roles if you are using identity. Simply call authorize and provide it with the Role name on a resource or a whole controller or even add more roles to the authorize like below:

```
[Authorize(Roles ="Clerk")]
```

I am authorizing a User Role with a name of Clerk on a certain resource. To add more roles simply add a comma after the clerk and add the other role name

Comment: Do note that adding a comma will cause it to OR the roles. If you want to AND the roles, put two separate Authorize attributes there, each with one role.